# How to rename a DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have DynamoDB table and I would like to rename it. There does not seems to be any commands or options to rename a table. Has anybody renamed a table before?

Answer (score 83):

I know this is an old question and I don't want to steal the thunder from user6500852's answer but for anyone stumbling upon this needing an answer:

1. Select the table you want to rename in the Web UI so it's highlighted and the various tabs show up to the right.
2. Click on the Backups tab and feast your eyes upon the lower half of the page ("On-Demand Backup and Restore").

[image: Backup Area]
3. Smash that "Create Backup" button. You'll be prompted for a backup name. Name it whatever you want. The world is yours!

4. Give it time to complete the backup. If you just have a few records, this will be seconds. If you have a ton of records it could be hours. Buckle up or just go home and get some rest.
5. Once the backup is ready, highlight it in the list. You'll see the "Restore Backup" button light up. Click it.
6. You'll get a prompt asking you to enter the NEW table name. Enter the name you wanted to rename this table to. Note: the way the UI is you may have to click out of the field in the static page area for the "Restore table" button at the bottom of the page to light up.
   [image: Restore Form]
7. Once you're ready to go, you click on the "Restore table" button. Note the info on that page indicating it can take several hours to complete. My table with just five test records took over 10 minutes to restore. I thought it was because the original was a Global Table but the restored table was NOT set up as a Global Table (which defeats the purpose of this for Global Tables since you have to empty the table to make it global).

**Bear in mind that last note!** If you're working with a Global Table, you will lose the Global part after the restore. Buyer beware! You may have to consider an export and import via Data Pipeline...

If you're not, then the Backup and Restore is a pretty easy process to use (without having to go and setup a pipeline, S3 store, etc.). It can just take some time.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This helped, though my table had Time to Live set up, and when I restored from backup that was gone, so that's another potential buyer beware warning

Comment: @user5305519 I appreciate the clean up a bit but editorializing an answer and including your own experience in my voice is a bit inappropriate, don't you think? You could just post your own answer or comment for that.

Comment: Note that if your table is managed through a CloudFormation stack and has a stream configured (and actively used by other resources in the stack), you'll have to go through an extra hoop (and not a small one). The stream will get lost in the backup/restore process, and if you recreate it manually, CloudFormation will still "remember" about the old one instead (thus leading to stack update errors as the old one no longer exists). Instead you'll need to delete all resources using that stream from the stack, then the stream config itself (on the table resource), then add all those things back up.

Answer (score 43):

Currently no, you would need to create a new table and copy the data from one to the other if you really needed a new table name.

Comment: You would just delete the old table when you are done copying all the old records to the new table.

Comment: I am forced to created additional tables to hold on to the data i want to copy over, because if a table is actively used in production i wont be able to delete it.

Comment: @Gowtham yes, that is true.  There are no synonyms in DynamoDB; if someone is querying table `foo` there is no way to make them query `bar` unless they push a change to their code in production.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the Export/Import feature to backup your data to S3. Then delete your old table, and create a new one with the new name. Import your data from S3. Done. No code change necessary. If you don't delete CloudWatch alarms and Pipelines when deleting the old table, then those will automatically hook up to the new table. The ARN even stays the same.

The downside to this, of course, is that the table will be unusable during the time after you delete it and before you recreate it. This may or may not be a problem, but that needs to be considered. Additionally, once you recreate the table, it can be accessed while you work on the data import. You may want to stop your app's access to the table until the import is complete.

Comment: `Create a new one with the same name. ` - I dont see how this is an answer to `I would like to rename it.`  ?    (yes, creating with a NEW name is the only path to renaming it...)

Answer (score 11):

Create first backup from backup tab. 
While creating restore backup, it prompt with request of new table name.

In that we can apply new/backup table name.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Screenshots of this process would be very useful.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to achieve this using on demand backup / restore functionality.

Check out a walk through on backing up a table, and restore to a new table:

https://www.abhayachauhan.com/2017/12/dynamodb-scheduling-on-demand-backups/