# Rename a table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table called `Transactions` in which I am recording an audit trail of activity in my app. After midnight I would like to rename the table to something like `Transactions.2015-10-01` and create a new table called `Transactions`, to which I would record the next 24 hours of activity in my app. At the end of that period I would rename that to `Transactions.2015-10-02` etc.

In other words, I'm trying to implement a rotating log of activity (though linear rather than circular).

I'm not sure there's a way to rename a table in DynamoDB. Is there a way? If not, is there another approach? For example, if there was a table pointer that was called `Transactions` that would point to `Transactions.2015-10-01` and then at midnight that pointer would switch to to `Transactions.2015-10-02`. My app audit logic would simply perform insertions into `Transactions` which delegates to the right table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename a DynamoDB table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410851/how-to-rename-a-dynamodb-table)

Comment: Just for the record: To me it feels weird to have one table for every day. DynamoDB tables are capable of scaling really big. You might want to use the adjacency list pattern instead, inside a single table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Amazon DynamoDB does not have a command to rename tables. The only table-related commands are `CreateTable`, `DeleteTable`, `DescribeTable`, `ListTables` and `UpdateTable` (which does not permit a rename).

Nor is there the ability to create aliases to tables.

The best approach would be for your application to create the desired tables and then direct transactions to the appropriate table.

Comment: Sadly I reencountered this situation this week.Thankfully it was sufficient to make property file changes. Lesson: don’t hardcore your table names, use System.getProperty()

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly a work around, but you can create a backup, restore the backup to a new table with a new name, then optionally remove the original table.

This is not a "rename", and it could break a lot of things. Just a hint. Don't go ahead and do it on your production server!

Comment: I like the lateral thinking!