# How to update existing table name in DynamoDB using AWS Cli?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

It may be a dumb question as I am beginner. I tried to update the existing table name (e.g. MusicCollection) in DynamoDB to "Music" using aws cli. But failed.

Here is the cli command I tried to use

aws dynamodb update-table --table-name MusicCollection | Music

Can someone tell me how to update the exiting table name by using aws cli or aws management console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898295/rename-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

This is the command to update your table from on-demand to provision:

```
aws dynamodb update-table --table-name YourTableName --billing-mode PROVISIONED --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=1,WriteCapacityUnits=1
```

and this is the command to update your provisioned table to on-demand:

```
aws dynamodb update-table --table-name YourTableName --billing-mode PAY_PER_REQUEST
```