# How to rename a table with AWS Dynamodb and boto3 API?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I want to rename in python an AWS DynamoDB table (with lots of items).

There's a way through backup management with the interface [1], but I need it with python boto3.

How to do it?

[1] [How to rename a DynamoDB table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410851/how-to-rename-a-dynamodb-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't rename a DynamoDB table.

Instead, create a new table, copy everything to it, and delete the old.

Here is an example (in Golang however): https://github.com/thumbtack/dynamodb-rename

And here are the Boto3 docs for DynamoDB: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html

As the APIs are all based on the underlying AWS Rest API, it should be easy to translate from Go to Python.